# In google cloud datastore, how do i create a filter for "IN" condition, that will do a "AND" of all the values supplied?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

So in my entity i have two properties that hold an array of values. I need to do a query on this Kind that will return to me all instances where each each instance has all the values mentioned in the filter for both properties. So the filter in short looks like this:

```
Filter filter1 = FilterOperator.IN.of(property1, listOfValuesToBeFiltered);
Filter filter2 = FilterOperator.IN.of(property2, anotherListOfValuesToBeFiltered);

Filter finalFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.AND.of(List containing filter1 and filter2);
```

The expectation is that entities that have all the values for property1 and all the values for property2 should be returned.

Right now the query returns any entity that has any one of the values for either property1 or property2.

How do I get the values "AND"ed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multiple IN filters with AND.

What you can is to create an additional property that will have combinations of p1 & p2.

So if you have `p1=[a,b, c], p2=[1,2,3]` then

`p3` will have `[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]`

and if you want to apply filter `p1 in [a, c] AND p2 in [2,3]` you would need to apply filter

```
p3 in [a2, a3, c2, c3]
```

what will give you what you want.

Comment: But what a single IN filter?  To carry your example forward, if I have 4 entities as follows: E1 -> p1 = [a,b], E2 -> p1 = [a,b,c,], E3 -> p1 = [a,c], E4 = [b,c]. Now if i create a Filter with IN for [a,c] , I do not want to see E4. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question in comment. And in comments there is no formatting so it's hard to present well. I believe my answer answers the original question. If it is satisfactory please upvote/accept. If you have another question please create a new one an post a link here in the comment and I'l try to have a look.

Comment: Ok, let me try to make it simple. If I am using an "IN" filter (a single filter, no composite) and I pass a list of values, the filter will "OR" all the values , right? How can I get an "IN" filter, that will "AND" all the values?

Comment: You simply do not use IN for AND as it's for OR only. You then need to use multiple AND like `p1 == 'a' AND p1 == 'b' AND p1 == 'c'`. But before doing this you should really study about exploding indexes (search & read!) and understand how GAE datastore indexes works.